# Async function leads to time out in Angular Karma testing

Tags: angular, asynchronous, testing, karma-runner

Karma is making me confused again.. This is how the test looks like, I call `httpMock.verify()` in `afterEach(..)`. The error message is `Error: Timeout - Async function did not complete within 5000ms`.

```
it('search user service should send GET request and return data', (done) => {
    let filter = '?filter=hans'
    inject([HttpTestingController, SearchUserService],
        (httpMock: HttpTestingController, service: SearchUserService) => {
            service.findUser(filter).subscribe(data => {
                expect(data).toBeTruthy();
                done();
            });

            const req = httpMock.expectOne(`http://localhost:8080/api/rest/frontend/user${filter}`)
            expect(req.request.method).toEqual('GET')

            req.flush({
                data:
                 {
                     ..
                 }
            });
    })
  });
```

The `findUser()` function returns an `Observable<any>`. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking your done callback does not get called. Put a console.log to ensure the code traverses inside of the subscribe block.

```
it('search user service should send GET request and return data', (done) => {
    let filter = '?filter=hans'
    inject([HttpTestingController, SearchUserService],
        (httpMock: HttpTestingController, service: SearchUserService) => {
            service.findUser(filter).subscribe(data => {
                expect(data).toBeTruthy();
                console.log('Calling done !!!!'); // Make sure you see this second
                done();
            });

            const req = httpMock.expectOne(`http://localhost:8080/api/rest/frontend/user${filter}`)
            expect(req.request.method).toEqual('GET')
            console.log('Giving response !!!!'); // make sure you see this first
            req.flush({
                data:
                 {
                     ..
                 }
            });
    })
  });
```